# Laravel action is not authorized

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a post that belongs to the user who made it, however i get this error(this was in the network log by the way)

> "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli42/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
>   line : 201 message : "This action is unauthorized." trace : [{,…},…]

I'm utilizing laravel 5.5 [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#writing-policies) not sure if im doing this right, i registered it in my AuthServiceProvider within **$protected policies**

`Post::class => PostPolicy::class,`

**Route**

`Route::delete('auth/post/{id}', 'PostController@destroy');`

**PostPolicy.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Post;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the post.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create posts.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the post.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the post.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //

        return $user->id === $post->user_id;

    }
```

**PostController.php** (there is more code to this file but i wanted to highlight the delete function)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\User;
use App\Policies\TaskPolicy; 


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function destroy($id, Post $post)
    {
        $mypost = $this->authorize('delete',$post);

        if($mypost){
             Post::destroy($id);

        }




    }
}
```

**Main.js** to delete post

```
$scope.deletePost = function(post){
    var index = $scope.myposts.indexOf(post);

    if(index != -1){
        $scope.myposts.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $http.delete('auth/post/' + post.id);

};
```

**html**

```
   <button ng-click="deletePost(post)">x</button>
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: showing us your route may help us identify your problem.

Comment: @Mark i updated the thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve the post, let Laravel does that for you.

Edit your route to be like this:

`Route::delete('auth/post/{post}', 'PostController@destroy');`

Note that the `post` between curly brackets will be the variable name assigned to the post if found by Laravel. If no post found, Laravel will return Not Found 404.

Then in your controller, you have to tell Laravel that you'r expecting a post coming through the route:

The method signuture will be like this: `destroy(Post $post)`. `$post` is the as `{post}` in your route.

Finally, for authorization, you will not get the post returned from `authorize method`. You pass the `$post` found by Laravel to the `authorize` method.

Here is the full method:

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('delete', $post);

    if ($post->delete()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'deleted']);
    };

    return response()->json(['error' => 'something went wrong'], 400);
}
```

Comment: @hamound i got one more question,

Comment: is there anyway to hide the delete `<button ng-click="deletePost(post)">x</button>` button for posts that does not belong to user using blade ?

Comment: untested. but try `@if( auth()->user()->can('delete', $post))`

Comment: Although, I don't know how you're using blade with angular. I'm not angular expert.

Comment: @hamound just got to switch up the symbols and angular and blade works just fine, but im running into a problem with post not being found, ill google into it.

Comment: `@foreach($posts as $post)
                        @if(Auth::user()->can('delete',$post))
                         <button ng-click="deletePost(post)">x</button>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach`

solved it, along with compact posts in my posts view.

Answer (score 3):

How about that... does that work?

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::first($id);
        $user = auth()->user();
        print_r($post);
        print_r($user);
        $mypost = $user->can('delete', $post);

        if($mypost){
             Post::destroy($id);
        }

    }
```

Comment: getting closer, i now get `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given`, not sure what this really means

Comment: I'm using angular to delete the post, could that be a factor ?

Comment: Just for fun, try that... make sure $post contains a valid post model instance and $user returns a logged in user... Wondering if that could not be one of your problems...

Comment: keep in mind im using this route to delete the post `Route::delete('auth/post/{id}', 'PostController@destroy');`

Comment: What ID do you pass from Angular? Same error where? At the Post::first($id) ? It has to resolve to a good Post instance.